# Using allow_utime with exfat

Tags: linux, permissions, mount, vfat, exfat

Considering the fact that exfat does not store ownership information of files, is it possible to mount an exfat partition in Linux with an allow_utime option that is also available for vfat? If not, is there a way to allow any process to use utime on any file in the filesystem?

I found an answer to this [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157523/fat-mountoption-allow-utime-explained/157605#157605), but this only applies to vfat. For the same reasons (no ownership information) it should theoretically also work with exfat, but I couldn't find any more information about it, and it didn't seem to work.

For Context: I have an ARM based laptop (Pinebook Pro) that has 64GB of internal memory and expandable storage via SD card. I would like to use Dropbox with it, but because this is an ARM laptop, I have to use alternative clients like [Maestral](https://maestral.app/). The internal storage is too small, so I opted to have it work with my 128GB SD card. I would also like to make the SD card portable and work with >4GB files, so I formatted it with exfat which should now have first class support in the kernel and avoids permission issues. Maestral needs to be able to use the utime() command to modify the access times of each file as it syncs with Dropbox, but it throws errors when I do it in the exfat filesystem, because it does not have permission. So this question is really trying to find a solution to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that allow_utime does work with the kernel exFAT driver, but not the olf FUSE driver as far as I can tell. My real issue was that I was using FUSE to mount the filesystem. After uninstalling exfat-utils, the OS mounted the drive using the kernel driver instead of FUSE, and it was able to use allow_utime just like vfat.